# IsolatedStorage causes Memory to run out

Tags: c#, memory-management, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

hey.
 I'm reading an image from Isolated Storage when the user clicks on an item like this:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile currentIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{

    using (var img = currentIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[img.Length];
        imgStream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        //read the imagestream into the byte array
        int read;
        while ((read = img.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            img.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        img.Close();
    }


}
```

This works fine, but if I click back and forth between two images, the memory consumption keeps increasing and then runs out of memory. Is there a more efficient way of reading images from Isolated Storage? I could cache a few images in memory, but with hundreds of results, it ends up taking up memory anyway. Any suggestions?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your code above doesn't actually do anything with imgStream

Comment: Sorry, imgStream is returned. The above code is in a method that returns MemoryStream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you disposing the `MemoryStream` at some point? This is the only leak I could find.

Also, `Stream` has a `CopyTo()` method. Your code could be rewritten like:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile currentIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var img = currentIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var imgStream = new MemoryStream(img.Length);

        img.CopyTo(imgStream);

        return imgStream;
    }
}
```

This will save many many memory allocations.

**EDIT:**

And for Windows Phone (which does not define a `CopyTo()`), replaced the `CopyTo()` method with it's code:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile currentIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var img = currentIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var imgStream = new MemoryStream(img.Length);

        var buffer = new byte[Math.Min(1024, img.Length)];
        int read;

        while ((read = img.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            imgStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);

        return imgStream;
    }
}
```

The main difference here is that the buffer is set relatively small (1K). Also, added an optimization by providing the constructor of `MemoryStream` with the length of the image. That makes `MemoryStream` pre-alloc the necessary space.

Comment: I figured the Using statement would do that. However, I removed the Using statement and manually disposed, but it still caused it to crash eventually.

Comment: I take it you are actually using the `MemoryStream` somewhere else? After you've consumed it, you need to dispose it. The `using` ensures that `Dispose()` is called at the end of the `using` block. You need to be done with it before that point.

Comment: Thanks. The MemoryStream is returned to the calling method. It seems that Windows Phone 7 doesn't have the CopyTo method as it doesn't appear in my intellisense. Is there an alternate method?

Comment: No, sorry. One moment, I'll update my answer with an alternative.

Comment: There you go. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pieter, that seems to work a lot quicker. I've spent days trying to fix this!