# How to get Photo stream after it has been manipulated to reduce size

Tags: windows-phone-7

using CameraCaptureTask to snap a photo.

Problem : The stream is not the same as g_stream = e.ChosenPhoto  when I use stream  photostream = g_MS which in the ReduceSize() Function.

I want to get the stream that same as  g_stream = e.ChosenPhoto  after the photo has been reduced in size in ReduceSize() function.

```
 stream g_stream;
 BitmapImage g_bmp;
 MemoryStream g_MS = new MemoryStream();

void task_Completed(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhotoResult e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
                {
                    g_bmp = new BitmapImage();

                    g_bmp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation; 

                    g_bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

        g_stream = e.ChosenPhoto;

                    ReduceSize();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }

private void ReduceSize()
{

 string m_Filenm = "Testing.jpg";  

      WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(g_bmp);

     //--wb read byte into memorystream

     System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, g_MS,800, 640, 0, 100);

    g_MS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);             


   stream  photostream = g_MS;


    //------------------ Save
    //--save in the photo Library under Saved Photo Collection

      MediaLibrary ML = new MediaLibrary();

     ML.SavePicture(m_Filenm, g_MS);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just retrieve the stream from your ReduceSize function:

```
stream g_stream;
BitmapImage g_bmp;
MemoryStream g_MS = new MemoryStream();

void task_Completed(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhotoResult e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            g_bmp = new BitmapImage();

            g_bmp.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation;

            g_bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

            g_stream = ReduceSize();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

private Stream ReduceSize()
{
    string m_Filenm = "Testing.jpg";

    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(g_bmp);

    //--wb read byte into memorystream

    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, g_MS, 800, 640, 0, 100);

    g_MS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    stream photostream = g_MS;

    //------------------ Save
    //--save in the photo Library under Saved Photo Collection

    MediaLibrary ML = new MediaLibrary();

    ML.SavePicture(m_Filenm, g_MS);

    g_MS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return g_MS;
}
```

Given that MediaLibrary.SavePicture doesn't close the stream, otherwise you'll have to copy it first.

Comment: Thanks. How can I get the photo stream first BEFORE saving in MediaLibrary?

Comment: I don't really understand why you would need that, so it might not be the answer you expect. You can make a copy of the stream before saving it to the MediaLibrary, then use the copy however you want. This link explains how to copy a stream: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127051/isolatedstorage-causes-memory-to-run-out

Comment: The reason I did this because this reduced photo's Kilobytes is reduced to 9-16Kb compare to 300 KB. I need to use this stream for uploading.

Comment: Sure, but why retrieving the stream before saving the picture to the MediaLibrary? Actually, why saving it at all? Anyway, you can also refactor your code to remove the MediaLibrary part from your ReduceSize method: Call the ReduceSize to retrieve the new stream, upload it, then call a SavePicture method, where you save the stream to the MediaLibrary.

Comment: Try your above method. after upload the stream, it show nothing.