# Getting "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream" saving jpg

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

What is wrong? I am getting this error "Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream" in this line:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("folder\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create))
```

First time runs ok, but not the second time.

```
string nameFile= e.UserState.ToString();
Stream stream = e.Result;   
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    if (!myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists("folder"))
    {
        myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory("folder");
        infoTextBlock.Text = "'folder' created...";
    }
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("folder\\" + fileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(fileStream);                                
    }
}
```

### UPDATED

Answering the questions:

**Exception:**

[System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException] = {"Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream."}

**StackTrace:**

```
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
   at NameApp.Backup.client_DownloadImatgesCompleted(Object sender, LiveDownloadCompletedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Live.LiveConnectClient.<>c__DisplayClass6.<RaiseDownloadCompletedEvent>b__4()
   at Microsoft.Live.SynchronizationContextWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Post>b__0(Object state)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
   at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
```

**I put breakpoint where I am using (fileStream) and these are the filenames:**

1st run:

Filenames:

- controlPic.txt
- PhotoChooser-c197865c-cbe6-4202-a95f-e4eeb16da943.jpg
- PhotoChooser-d1d0c947-664f-425b-aaa2-85b17a4a73ec.jpg
- PhotoChooser-4ce1b884-8d7f-444e-925d-2ca2ae2b3b7c.jpg

2nd run:

Filenames:

- controlPic.txt

here crash, but the variable "NameFile" contains the correct names:

- PhotoChooser-c197865c-cbe6-4202-a95f-e4eeb16da943.jpg
- PhotoChooser-d1d0c947-664f-425b-aaa2-85b17a4a73ec.jpg
- PhotoChooser-4ce1b884-8d7f-444e-925d-2ca2ae2b3b7c.jpg

### UPDATED 2

I have seen that the problem happens after upload files. I have seen that I am getting exception when I try to open, delete, overwrite, etc. files that have previously been uploaded ...

I am using this code:

```
private void UploadFilePictures()

using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
   this.client.UploadCompleted
                    += new EventHandler<LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs>(ISFileImatges_UploadCompleted);

   foreach (string fileName in myIsolatedStorage.GetFileNames("folder\\*.jpg"))
   {

      fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("folder\\" + fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
      this.client.UploadAsync(skyCarpetaImatges_ID, fileName, true, fileStream, null);    
   }
}
}




   private void ISFileImatges_UploadCompleted(object sender, LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
              fileStream.Close();
              fileStream.Dispose()

    this.client.UploadCompleted -= new EventHandler<LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs>(ISFileImatges_UploadCompleted);
}
```

### SOLUTION:

SEE COMMENTS IN MARKED SOLUTION

Comment: Also, please, for both cases (1st run and 2nd run), break on your using (fileStream) statement and tell us what nameFile is.

Comment: I have updated my question to reply your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("folder\\" + fileName,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write,myIsolatedStorage ))
     {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                  writer.WriteLine(data);
                  writer.Close();
            }
            stream.Close();
      }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Milan. I have tried but I am getting the same error. I have updated my question.

Comment: updated code. This is working for me. If this doesn't work, then try using the [**IS tool**](http://istool.codeplex.com/) to see what actually is happening inside your IS on run-time.

Comment: This maybe happening because of not closing the stream. Now try the updated code. See if it helps. Else after running the code. try IS tool link above to see what actually gets saved in your folder.

Comment: Hi Milan: I am copying images (.jpg) except one (is a txt file), I can not use "writer.WriteLine". But with "using(IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = etc etc)" it is not necessary do "close ()" right?

Comment: see the `answer` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127051/isolatedstorage-causes-memory-to-run-out) It is similar to what you are doing. See if it helps. Everywhere I see people have closed the stream. Looks like its recommended. If its not going to cause any problem you should close it too.

Comment: Hi Milan: getting same error. Now if I try the next code, before accessing the file, "DeleteFile" throw same exception: if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists("folder\\" + fileName)
{
         myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile("folder\\" + fileName);
}

It seems as if these files were in use.

Comment: I've updated my question because I have seen that the problem happens after upload file. See "Updated 2".

Comment: 1) where have you associated the `ISFileImatges_UploadCompleted` function to an event?
2) since you are following async, by the time its uploaded filestream value is changed since its a foreach loop and hence it gives error because you are trying to dispose wrong filestream. You need to somehow send the stream to your eventhandler. Check if its an argument in sender or eventargs parameters. If not you would have to create eventargs manually.

Comment: Hi Milan: 1)i've updated code. `ISFileImatges_UploadComplete` is code previous "foreach". 2) but how to dispose the filestream concrete?

Comment: I guess put the UploadCompleted inside the for each loop **after** this statement `fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("folder\\" + fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);`. I say this because once you associate this event in the for each loop, threads will be initiated and when the event is triggered it should be able to access its respective filestream value. This is only a hunch. I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Milan: I have tried but i am getting news errors. Because if I put "uploadCompleted" within "foreach", "UploadCompleted" is multiplied by the number of files. For example, if I upload 5 files, this event is fire 25 times (5 * 5). If I put it out (before foreach) is fired well (only the number of times = files uploaded). And when "uploadCompleted" fires, and run this line: fileStream.Dispose(),display this error: Cannot access a closed file.

Comment: What if you create a local client and not a global client? have you tried that? (With the uploadedContent inside the foreach) I guess then for each client's uploaded method a thread will be created and hence it should do the trick. I hope

Comment: solved! you was in correct way. Filestream improperly disposing. I have modified Upload:  this.client.UploadAsync(skyCarpetaImatges_ID, nomFitxer, true, fileStream, fileStream); and after in "uploadCompleted", example: var pepito = args.UserState as IsolatedStorageFileStream ;
                if (pepito != null)
                {
                    pepito.Dispose ();
                }

Comment: great.. glad to be of help :)