# Definition of resource ID not found when trying to write to IsolatedStorageFile

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone, isolatedstorage, streamwriter

I'm trying to write a string to an IsolatedStorageFile, but I'm getting an IsolatedStorageException, the link in the exception is this one:

```
http://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/DllResourceIDs/Default.aspx?Version=4.0.50829.0&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=IsolatedStorage_Operation_ISFS
```

And it states that the definition of 'resource ID' could not be found. I have no idea why this exception occurs, here's my code:

```
private void writeListToStorage(List<PlanningItemModel> items)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if(myIsolatedStorageFile.FileExists("Zomerparkfeesten\\" + filePath))
        {
            IsolatedStorageFileStream iStream = myIsolatedStorageFile.OpenFile("Zomerparkfeesten\\" + filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write);
            string json = Converter.convertListOfItemsToJson(items);
            StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(iStream);
            try
            {
                writeFile.WriteLine(json);
                writeFile.Close();
                iStream.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {
                writeFile.Close();
                iStream.Close();
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            myIsolatedStorageFile.CreateFile("Zomerparkfeesten\\" + filePath);
            this.writeListToStorage(items);
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the folder Zomerparkfeesten created? In which line does it break?

Comment: Yes, the folder exists it breaks whenever I try to execute an operation on the myIsolatedStorageFile. I've tried OpenFile and DeletFile and it throws the exception everytime.

Comment: Have you tried the following syntax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625910/getting-operation-not-permitted-on-isolatedstoragefilestream-saving-jpg (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("folder\\" + fileName,FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write,myIsolatedStorage ))

Comment: Alright, I've implemented it but it still throws the exception.

Comment: Right now it's ALWAYS throwing an exception when I try to execute an operation on the IsolatedStorageFile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And it states that the definition of 'resource ID' could not be found

No, that's not what it says.  Odd problem, might have something to do with you speaking Dutch instead of English.  Looks like they fumbled the Dutch localization of this particular exception.  When I visit that URL from the USA, I get:

> Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream

Which of course makes a lot more sense, given the code snippet.  I can't get you a lot more help beyond that, basic issue is that your program doesn't have write access to isolated storage.  You'll need to give it access.

One nasty failure mode that's hard to diagnose, this code will always blow up with "Operation not permitted" when you pass an empty string for "filePath".  That will make the code try to write a file that has the same name as an existing directory, that's never permitted.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question! Do you know if there is any way to get to the english version of the link? Disabling localization, errors like the one I got aren't going to help me much in the future. Thanks for the clear answer!

Comment: That did not work, I've tried installing software like the Hola extension but it didn't change the error message either.

Comment: I changed the language setting on the Microsoft site itself, and it changed the error message. Weird inconvenient bug.

Comment: Best thing to do is to just get it fixed.  I reported the bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/811271/bad-localization-for-silverlight-exception-message

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
 using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                if (!myIsolatedStorageFile.DirectoryExists("Zomerparkfeesten"))
                {
                    myIsolatedStorageFile.CreateDirectory("Zomerparkfeesten");
                    myIsolatedStorageFile.CreateFile("Zomerparkfeesten//" + filePath);

                }
                else
                {
                    if (!myIsolatedStorageFile.FileExists("Zomerparkfeesten//" + filePath))
                    {
                        myIsolatedStorageFile.CreateFile("Zomerparkfeesten//" + filePath);
                    }

                }

                using (Stream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Zomerparkfeesten//" + filePath, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, myIsolatedStorageFile))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                    {
                        writer.WriteLine("Test");// some your data
                        writer.Close();
                        stream.Close();
                    }
                }

            }
```